# css full width modal overlay below button

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table like this:
[image: tTable with buttons]

I would like when I press (Button1) the result to be this:
[image]

And when I press (Button2) the result to be this:
[image]

Hi level html mock-up:

```
<div id="item-warapper">
    <div id="item-header">  
        <label>Entity Title</label>
    </div>
    <div id="item-detail">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>detail ID</td>
                    <td>detail Quantity</td>
                    <td>detail Value</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <tr id="row1">
                        <td>
                            001
                            <button>Open Detail</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>5.00</td>
                        <td>200.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row2">
                        <td>002</td>
                        <td>7.00
                            <button>Quantity Details</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>300.00</td>
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td>003</td>
                        <td>9.00</td>
                        <td>
                            500.00
                            <button>Value Details</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                                       
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>  
    <div>
        <div id="detail-item-view">
            <!-- Some detail -->
        </div>
        <div id="detail-quantity-view">
            <!-- Some detail -->
        </div>      
        <div id="detail-value-view">
            <!-- Some detail -->
        </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: include CODE and CSS!

Comment: what you wan to create called accordion: here is an implementation: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twitter's bootstrap has solved this really good. Have a look at this one here: [getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

I have created a little example right here:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FEFEFE;
  border: 1px dotted #BEBEBE;
}
.container-row {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}
.container-row:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.container-row + .container-row {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Ressources -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Example -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Button 1
    </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Button 2
    </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
      <div class="inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your overlay needs to be absolutely positioned at the bottom of the button. You can find the bottom of the button with the following Jquery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // show the overlay
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
    // calcs bottom of button 
    var bottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(true);
    $('#overlay').css({
        'top': bottom + 'px',

    });
});
```

Here's a codepen to demonstrate what I mean: http://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/LZGvZP

NB: As you are positioning the overlay absolutely make sure that you have a position relative on a parent wrappper that contains both the table and the overlay markup (in my example I added it to the body).

EDIT: You've added markup after I wrote this but this should demonstrate the principle.